# SQLite DELETE condition , Firefox History

Tags: sqlite, firefox

how delete the results of this query?, replicate these conditions but with the DELETE.

this query returns last visited site, I would use same conditions to delete history, is necessary convert syntax to "DELETE FROM" and use the same criteria please help .. thanks.

```
SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch') AS 'Date Visited', moz_places.title AS Title, moz_places.url AS URL, moz_places.visit_count AS Count FROM moz_historyvisits, moz_places WHERE moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id ORDER BY moz_historyvisits.visit_date ASC
```

or this

```
SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') as data, moz_places.url
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've completely understood your question, but if you want to selectively delete associated entries from both `moz_places` and `moz_historyvisits`, then you should be able to use something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW delenda AS
  SELECT id FROM moz_places WHERE ($condition);

DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE place_id IN (SELECT id FROM delenda);
DELETE FROM moz_places WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM delenda);
```

(Replace $condition with your criteria for deletion.)

Comment: example 2. this query returns last visited site, I would use same conditions to delete history so this condition working fine , is necessary convert syntax to DELETE FROM and use the same criteria below `SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch') AS 'Date Visited', moz_places.title AS Title, moz_places.url AS URL, moz_places.visit_count AS Count FROM moz_historyvisits, moz_places WHERE moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id ORDER BY moz_historyvisits.visit_date ASC`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `WITH ..... DELETE` where `....` is a **CTE** (Common Table Expression) which equates to your query. Alternately you could use the query as a **sub query** of the DELETE's WHERE clause.

However, all you need from the query, for the deletion is enough data to identify the row to be deleted. Assuming that the table **isn't a WITHOUT ROWID** table, then the **rowid** of the selected table would suffice.

As such the following would work :-

#### Solution 1 (WITH ..... DELETE)

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid IN (SELECT rid FROM cte1);
```

- Note that `datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') as data, moz_places.url` aren't needed and have therefore been excluded from the CTE (they could be included).

#### Solution 2 DELETE using SubQuery in the WHERE clause

Alternately you could use the query (again just retrieving the rowid) a a subquery of the WHERE clause, as per :-

```
DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid IN 
    (SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
    FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
    WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
    ORDER BY 1 desc
    LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
;
```

#### Example Code used for Testing

The following is the code used to test the above:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moz_places;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moz_historyvisits;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moz_historyvisits (place_id INTEGER, visit_date);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moz_places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, URL TEXT, title TEXT, visit_count INTEGER);


-- Add Some data
INSERT INTO moz_places (URL) VALUES('Rome'),('London'),('Paris'),('Sydney'),('Tokyo');
INSERT INTO moz_historyvisits VALUES(1,'2010-10-11 10:30'),(2,'2018-01-31 12:20'),(1,'2018-02-28 08:15'),(3,'2017-06-01 15:45');

-- Result 1 (show original data)
SELECT * FROM moz_historyvisits JOIN moz_places ON moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id;


-- Result 2 (test the CTE by selecting everything extracted by the CTE)
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') AS data, moz_places.url, moz_places.id, moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
SELECT * FROM cte1;

-- This does deleteion using WITH ..... DELETE
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid IN (SELECT rid FROM cte1);

-- Result 43show table after deletion
SELECT * FROM moz_historyvisits JOIN moz_places ON moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id;

-- Do alternative/equivakent deletion via subquery
DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid IN(SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0);

-- Result 4 show table after both deletions
SELECT * FROM moz_historyvisits JOIN moz_places ON moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id;
```

#### Resultant Outputs

Result 1 -

[image: ![enter image description here]

Result 2 -

[image]

Result 3 -

[image]

Result 4 -

[image]

Messages -

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moz_places
> OK
> Time: 0.356s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moz_historyvisits
> OK
> Time: 0.324s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moz_historyvisits (place_id INTEGER, visit_date)
> OK
> Time: 0.358s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moz_places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, URL TEXT, title TEXT, visit_count INTEGER)
> OK
> Time: 0.333s


-- Add Some data
INSERT INTO moz_places (URL) VALUES('Rome'),('London'),('Paris'),('Sydney'),('Tokyo')
> Affected rows: 5
> Time: 0.265s


INSERT INTO moz_historyvisits VALUES(1,'2010-10-11 10:30'),(2,'2018-01-31 12:20'),(1,'2018-02-28 08:15'),(3,'2017-06-01 15:45')
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.354s


-- Result 1 (show original data)
SELECT * FROM moz_historyvisits JOIN moz_places ON moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id
> OK
> Time: 0s


-- Result 2 (test the CTE by selecting everything extracted by the CTE)
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') AS data, moz_places.url, moz_places.id, moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
SELECT * FROM cte1
> OK
> Time: 0s


-- Do alternative/equivakent deletion via subquery
DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid IN(SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.228s


-- Result 4 show table after both deletions
SELECT * FROM moz_historyvisits JOIN moz_places ON moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id
> OK
> Time: 0s


-- This does deleteion using WITH ..... DELETE
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0)
DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid IN (SELECT rid FROM cte1)
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s


-- Result 43show table after deletion
SELECT * FROM moz_historyvisits JOIN moz_places ON moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id
> OK
> Time: 0s
```

Comment: Thank you @MikeT still not work. the comparisons in Example 2.  `moz_historyvisits.visit_date compare -> moz_places.url + moz_places.id -> moz_historyvisits.place_id` these is the variants names correct. please correct rowid my tests have not been successful

Comment: in my test but not  we do not get the same result as the original query skips some URLs

Comment: Considering that you supplied no example data nor the table schema, the example data used was made up based upon the available information. The example showed the **principle* of either using a **subquery** or a **CTE**, along with the utilising the **rowid** and was based upon the second example. If the rows aren't being selected as required then the issue is with WHERE/LIMIT/ORDER clauses that you supplied, the columns extracted are basically irrelevant.

Comment: I have done many tests I can not find the correct syntax.  think something wrong on `moz_historyvisits.visit_date moz_places.url.` not get the same result on delete and on the main query in delete case only 1 rows effected in orinal query 11 rows found
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK0N7.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtrFD.png

Comment: this example works but delete 1 rows for time how to delete all the row in same time?  thanks   `DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_historyvisits.rowid = 
    (SELECT moz_historyvisits.rowid AS rid
    FROM   moz_places, moz_historyvisits 
    WHERE  moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id)
;`

Comment: I think I understand, the query returns a number of rows whilst I took *"this query returns last visited site"* to mean just 1 row is returned. As such instead of using **`=`** using **`IN`** will delete all the extracted **rowid**'s and hence rows that were selected. Answer has been changed accordingly.

Comment: @Giorgio could you please mark the question as answered.